# readline() only reading the first line

Tags: python

I'm trying to read multiple lines in a file and it doesn't seem to work when I assigned my `readline()` method to a variable. It keeps printing the first line. It only seems to work when I don't assign it to a variable. Any ideas?

I'm using Python 3.6.2. Here is my code:

```
# This is it not working ( I omitted the 'gradesfile_path' variable)

gradesfile = open(gradesfile_path,'r')
readgrades = gradesfile.readline()

print(readgrades)
print(readgrades)

# This is working when I don't call the variable

print(gradesfile.readline())
print(gradesfile.readline())
print(gradesfile.readline())
```

Comment: Are you sure the first line is not empty. Because its working for me

Comment: The assignment does not assign the function call to the variable. It simply assigns the first line when the function is called.

Comment: `readgrades` will contain the result of reading the line... It doesn't change unless you do another `readgrades = gradesfile.readline()`...

Comment: I just tried that out and it worked as you stated..didn't realize i need to call it again. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readline()` reads a single line -- the *next* line in the context of the iterator returned by `open()`. And you are assigning *the line read* as variable `readgrades` which will always contain that line.

Perhaps you meant to assign the method to a variable and call that variable instead:

```
readgrades = gradesfile.readline  ##Note the absence of call
```

Then you can do:

```
readgrades()
```

Comment: I liked this answer but the essence of it that: .readline is a method and .readline() is a function call to that method is not described with a red thread +.1

Comment: thanks so much!  code is now working as expected, I can now proceed to looping through the file... thanks again

Answer (score 1):

When you assign `gradesfile.readline()` to a variable, you are actually reading one line and storing that line to the variable

Answer (score 1):

**readline()** is suppose to read the whole file as line by line, so I believe you need to keep calling it everytime you need to read a line and If you're not restricted to use readline(), then your objective can be achieved using:

> **read()**:- will read the whole file at once
>
> **readlines()**:- will read the whole file and result it into python list

```
with open('file_name', 'r') as file_obj:
    print file_obj.readlines()
```

or

```
with open('file_name', 'r') as file_obj:
    some_var = file_obj.readlines()
    print some_var
```

or

```
with open('file_name', 'r') as file_obj:
    print file_obj.read()
```

or

```
with open('file_name', 'r') as file_obj:
    some_var = file_obj.read()
    print some_var
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have to replace `readline()` with `readlines()`. `Readline()` returns only the first line whereas `readlines()` returns all lines of your file.

Comment: Talat Parwez already provided that answer over six years ago. Please don't repeat answers.